# Flutter Code Formatting Issues in VSCode: how can I fix Misaligned Child Widgets and Inconsistent Indentation?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm facing challenges with Flutter code formatting in Visual Studio Code. Child widgets aren't aligning properly beneath their parent, and attributes lack consistent indentation. Any tips or settings adjustments to address this issue?
This picture is after the automatically formatting.
[image]
It looks weird.
I added the following commands to the settings.json

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add trailing commas (`,`) at the end of your parenthesis `)`.

From [the documentation:](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas):

> To get good automatic formatting, we recommend you adopt the optional
> trailing commas. The guideline for adding a trailing comma is simple:
> Always add a trailing comma at the end of a parameter list in
> functions, methods, and constructors where you care about keeping the
> formatting you crafted. This helps the automatic formatter to insert
> an appropriate amount of line breaks for Flutter-style code.

[image]

Also, don't forget to format on save through *Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Formatting*:

[image]